# What are the steps to verify the inputs and outputs of a transaction. Excluding steps requiring blockchain access

Tags: transactions, validation

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "locktime": 0,
  "vin": [
    {
      "txid": "1d8f38f6a5fbc7951568f64f3b9320a4ebd1053dce4641a5c5526d3cd7a805e1",
      "vout": 0,
      "prevout": {
        "scriptpubkey": "76a914293aa0e106ce67e0a538f79eba12be042012376488ac",
        "scriptpubkey_asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 293aa0e106ce67e0a538f79eba12be0420123764 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "scriptpubkey_type": "p2pkh",
        "scriptpubkey_address": "14kzwSXGFcnmxypPuSGsXw2AJ6QYHMvAmW",
        "value": 43640
      },
      "scriptsig": "47304402205112f96bf7423703c221976603307f0e33913d39efc3344d68376fd2b8c0bd20022003ea588c06fa1a3e262e07ed6bf01a36f78741fe7bc6a91ff43c38a0a14e43fe012103bf68f1ce783df58a2459d549d5c655a1edc0f0cf4d79421fe978d358d79ee42a",
      "scriptsig_asm": "OP_PUSHBYTES_71 304402205112f96bf7423703c221976603307f0e33913d39efc3344d68376fd2b8c0bd20022003ea588c06fa1a3e262e07ed6bf01a36f78741fe7bc6a91ff43c38a0a14e43fe01 OP_PUSHBYTES_33 03bf68f1ce783df58a2459d549d5c655a1edc0f0cf4d79421fe978d358d79ee42a",
      "witness": null,
      "is_coinbase": false,
      "sequence": 4294967295,
      "inner_redeemscript_asm": null
    },
    {
      "txid": "6f7d353fb1c3af2694b54e268e9207ea59d1b699f56fc38fb0b4f410c1b6f36b",
      "vout": 1,
      "prevout": {
        "scriptpubkey": "76a9146012eb3f170e34c880d4d8f2e191e51940d23ad688ac",
        "scriptpubkey_asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 6012eb3f170e34c880d4d8f2e191e51940d23ad6 OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
        "scriptpubkey_type": "p2pkh",
        "scriptpubkey_address": "19kzXviUHUMLqbc3GgTN8jSC8iSoaYnGDw",
        "value": 221273
      },
      "scriptsig": "483045022100ccd24f74db54fc839996bf375d5a022fd7a7dbbab061f1dbe807e34ea2e365bc02206bf0f95a1018eee9ac868de517ff185a28d507cbc92972597a37604b5232ba34012103526b9a0a4ddcd0fc1cf7f0b5f4d202bc587ff44b7c253c68000b9e49a9434442",
      "scriptsig_asm": "OP_PUSHBYTES_72 3045022100ccd24f74db54fc839996bf375d5a022fd7a7dbbab061f1dbe807e34ea2e365bc02206bf0f95a1018eee9ac868de517ff185a28d507cbc92972597a37604b5232ba3401 OP_PUSHBYTES_33 03526b9a0a4ddcd0fc1cf7f0b5f4d202bc587ff44b7c253c68000b9e49a9434442",
      "witness": null,
      "is_coinbase": false,
      "sequence": 4294967295,
      "inner_redeemscript_asm": null
    }
  ],
  "vout": [
    {
      "scriptpubkey": "a914e00f79d486ff476db46eb6e188a5d31b5429a91387",
      "scriptpubkey_asm": "OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 e00f79d486ff476db46eb6e188a5d31b5429a913 OP_EQUAL",
      "scriptpubkey_type": "p2sh",
      "scriptpubkey_address": "3N7jpoF34rPZp6WmcBmNxwpKAZZQCqDgbo",
      "value": 252238
    },
    {
      "scriptpubkey": "76a91441e4631b03326762604016821070aa95d7b15fde88ac",
      "scriptpubkey_asm": "OP_DUP OP_HASH160 OP_PUSHBYTES_20 41e4631b03326762604016821070aa95d7b15fde OP_EQUALVERIFY OP_CHECKSIG",
      "scriptpubkey_type": "p2pkh",
      "scriptpubkey_address": "171QX5w3Jvi5udAim7MyWhDRgeETfqZsTz",
      "value": 771
    }
  ]
}
```

In this type of transaction format, and we do not have access to the previous blockchain, what are the steps to verify the inputs and outputs of the transaction. Assume that the PrevOut in the inputs are correct and they exist in the blockchain.

Comment: The main confusion is which components I have to include in the trimmed transaction that i will prepare for signature verification of the inputs.